# Django register form

Tags: python, django

so, I made the registration page with django and it doesn't show the form
register.html

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.as_table }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='submit' value="Register">
</form>
```

and this is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')    
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', { 'form ' : form})


def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

And all it shows is the register button

Comment: What if you use `{{ form }}` instead. Are you sure that the template is rendered by the `register` view?

Answer (score 1):

Could be one of two things:

- Put the {% csrf_token %} before the form variable in your template.
- Don't put any whitspace in the form key in your context dictionary (so instead of ' form ' it should be 'form')

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistakenly wrote "form " instead of "form" and also put {% csrf_token %} in the form tag right before the rendering